# Как с помощью JS прочитать куки созданные yii2?

Tags: javascript, yii2, cookie

На yii 2 бэкенде пользователю пишутся куки, как на фронте с помощью JS можно их прочитать и если надо, изменить?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: @BearVorkuta только куки созданные в yii2 имеют другой формат

Comment: как вы их пишете, можете показать?

Comment: @BearVorkuta ada8db918de785a8bace5e3fdb8e46ed466ae7b68ed7aa992ec6423588f2c2d3a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A3%3A%22UVS%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A57%3A%22%5B%7B%22q%22%3A%22%22%2C%22l%22%3A%22New%20York%20City%22%2C%22lid%22%3A3832%2C%22ts%22%3A1616418677%7D%5D%22%3B%7D

Comment: а если использовать decodeURIComponent() для вашей куки?

Comment: @BearVorkuta в yii2 куки шифруются за счёт cookieValidationKey поэтому обычные js куки тут не работают

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский принял, намотал на ус )